# iPhone - Optimizing drawRect

Tags: iphone, optimization, uiview, core-graphics, drawrect

I have overriden an UIView to make some custom draw :

```
// ========================================================================================
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    float alphaStep = (kMaxAlpha - kMinAlpha) / (self.nbLines - 1);
    float alphaValue = kMaxAlpha;

    float lineToDrawY = self.headLineYPos;
    float lineWidth = kScanLineMaxWidth;
    float lineWidthStep = (kScanLineMaxWidth - kScanLineMinWidth) / (self.nbLines - 1);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    for (int i=1; i<=self.nbLines; i++) {

        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [self.scanColor colorWithAlphaComponent:alphaValue].CGColor);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, lineToDrawY);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, [self bounds].size.width, lineToDrawY);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        lineToDrawY -= kOneLineJumpDistance;

        lineWidth = MAX(0.5, lineWidth - lineWidthStep);
        alphaValue = MAX(0, alphaValue - alphaStep);
    }
}
```

self.nbLines may be around 30-40, may be 100.

But this part of the drawing is very time consuming and I'm not able to make a screen update each 2 or 3 ms. This is needed to keep the screen animation total time under a second (I move the head line each xxx ms by xxx pixels, but increasing this too much causes flickering).

How can I optimize this ?

Comment: How many `nbLines` are you expecting?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer : around 30-40, may be 100

Comment: And it's taking how many milliseconds to draw? Updating every 2 or 3 milliseconds is going to be a hard target to hit. That's 333 - 500 fps, which I'm pretty certain the iPhone can't (and doesn't want to) hit.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer : on the phone for 100 calls and 56 lines, it's around 750 ms believing "Instruments"

Comment: And you're certain it's your drawing code and not something else?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer : I believe optimization is possible because lowering the number of lines reduces the time. The problem does not seems to be the refresh time but the way lines are drawn.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer : It's 100% my code. Not a semicolon more or less

Comment: What exactly are you drawing? Not just lines, but is there a way you can draw an image instead of so many lines?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer : I'm writing a scanline. Some lines are thicker than the other, and their alpha value change too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are actually changing/animating every line segment and not just adding a segment to the end, then switching to using OpenGL ES for your drawing may be the only option that allows a high enough animation frame rate.  On iOS devices, Open GL will render the polygons (lines) using GPU hardware rather than stroking lines in software as CG drawing does.

If you are only adding or changing the segments near the end, then a compositing approach may work (using multiple CALayers), where you don't re-render a large group of segments that don't change every frame.

Also, the max frame rate on iOS devices is 60 Hz, so you don't need to render more often the once every 16.6 mS.  Re-rendering every 2 or 3 mS will be invisible to the display.

Comment: do you mean that I won't be able to draw a single line up to down 1 pixel by 1 pixel on a 320 pixel distance in less than 320 x 16.6 = 5312 ms ? That's not correct, I do that in 1.5 seconds without "jumps" that would happen if one step wasn't displayed.

Comment: @Oliver - The physical LCD display doesn't actually update any more often than once every 60th of a second.  So that's the smallest possible time interval in which you can see any visible "jump".  That's fairly fast compared with movie film that only changes frames at 24 FPS and still provides the illusion of motion.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately drawRect isn't the best place to do animations.  I think the reason why is because the result of drawRect gets copied into a new texture (a CALayer) and then shown on the screen.

If the animation you want to do can't be accomplished with UIView animations or CoreAnimation something you can do are:

1. Make sure you aren't calling needsDisplay on unnecessarily often. Once you draw something once, the result is cached in a CALayer so drawRect should only need to be called when something changes.
2. Since you are making a view that updates a lot, try using needsDisplayInRect instead of needsDisplay.  Then refactor your code to only update the portion passed in drawRect.
3. If you still don't get the performance you need, you should look into drawing to the CGLayer directly or using a library like [cocos2d](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/)

Comment: I think you mean CALayer, not CGLayer.  CGLayers are used within Core Graphics for drawing elements.  CALayers are the Core Animation layers that back UIViews, and what the UIViews get rendered into.

Comment: @JoeBlow I should've said "drawRect isn't the best place to do animations."  It is possible to animate inside drawRect if you use NSTimers to property place calls to needsDisplay but it's generally much easier to make smooth animations using animatable UIView properties or CoreAnimation. Not to mention that the later is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a possibility to use CoreAnimation if you can divide your picture into layers that only move over each other. AFAIK does the drawing then appear only once and the composing is done by the GPU.

Maybe you could draw the head line, which should be animated on a separate layer and then animate this layer using CoreAnimation.

I am not sure if that is helpful in any sense as I cannot imagine what you are drawing from the drawing code alone.